# Does the singularity clear fog?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I was playing I noticed that the singularity ability seemed to clear the smoke from the grenades, is this just a coincidence or does it have an effect on it?

Comment: if it really does, that's a nice touch

Comment: I'm 90% certain it does, because that's what I used it for sometimes if I had Liara with me, but I have no proof so my answer would just be "Yes."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried multiple attempts, and recorded every attempt (for science). Although I could have sworn that I have seen this effect myself, my guess is the smoke grenade ends its duration and if a singularity is present, there is a chance it gets "sucked in" as an easter egg animation.

However, the singularity itself does not specifically reduce the time of the smoke grenade. Here is a video of one of the attempts, showing a clear lack of singularity vacuuming.

Answer (score 0):

In my attempts, I was unable to use singularity to clear smoke. I tried testing at various points within the smoke cloud but was unable to get this to occur.